# Android - Adding Views to Images doesn't update - onClick

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

**Summary**

When a user clicks on the `RecyclerView` item, I would like to add tags to that image from the information that has been stored in a BaaS [Sashido] (X Co-ordinates, Y Co-ordinates and Tag name). But, the problem I'm having isn't getting the position per-say. I create a toast when the image has been clicked, it shows the correct position corresponding to the view itself. (zero for the beginning, so on and so forth)

But how to update the position once the user clicks on another item in the list, so that the tags that correspond to the position in the array in Sashido, match the position in the `RecyclerView`, because at the moment the first row in the Sashido class is populating all images with that row's tags.

My assumption was to the pass the position to the `getTagInformation()` method using `getLayoutPosition()` so that when `objects.get(position)` array is called, it'll get the same position for Sashido class but it isn't. I feel the adapter must not be updating correctly after the user has clicked on a new item.

*onBindViewHolder:*

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolderPreviousPosts holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(previousPostsList.get(position), listener);
}
```

*onBind:*

```
void bind(final PreviousPostsDataModel model, final OnItemClickListener listener) { ...

uploadedImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (count == 0) {
                            imageid = model.getImageId();
                            Toast.makeText(App.getContext(), "Image ID: " + imageid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(App.getContext(), "Position: " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            getTagInformation(getLayoutPosition());
                        } else {
                            Log.e("qwert", "" + imageid);
                            imageContainer.removeAllViews();
                            imageContainer.addView(uploadedImage);
                            count = 0;
                        }
                }
            });
... }
```

*getTagInformation:*

```
private void getTagInformation(final int position) {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FashionFeed");
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            JSONArray tagNamesArray = objects.get(position).getJSONArray("tagName");
                            JSONArray posXArray = objects.get(position).getJSONArray("tagPointX");
                            JSONArray posYArray = objects.get(position).getJSONArray("tagPointY");

                            for (int i = 0; i < tagNamesArray.length(); i++) {
                                for (int t = 0; t < tagNamesArray.length(); t++) {
                                    tagNames.add(tagNamesArray.optString(t));
                                    tagXPositions.add(posXArray.optString(t));
                                    tagYPositions.add(posYArray.optString(t));

                                }

                                for (int o = 0; o < tagNamesArray.length(); o++) {
                                    tag = new TextView(App.getContext());
                                    tag.setX(Float.parseFloat(tagXPositions.get(o)));
                                    tag.setY(Float.parseFloat(tagYPositions.get(o)));
                                    tag.setText(tagNames.get(o));
                                    tag.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                    tag.setMaxLines(1);
                                    tag.setTextSize(11);
                                    tag.setClickable(true);
                                    tag.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tag.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tags_rounded_corners);
                                    imageContainer.addView(tag);
                                    count = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

I have also tried

```
public void getTagInformation(String imageid) {
ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FashionFeed");
query.WhereEqualTo("objectId", imageId);
....
}
```

with the `imageId` passed into the method and with also me manually entering an `objectId` that will match, it'll still only produce the tags that belong to that `objectId`. it just doesn't seem that this query is going through all of the objects. Just getting the tag information from that one object and then setting all the images with those tags.

if you need me to provide anymore code, I'm more than happy to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. It wasn't so much that the position was wrong, it was because I was trying to find the tags before I was populating the list of images due to Parse's `FindInBackground()` callback, it was being populated far too late.

The solution was that I got the `JSONArray` that contained the Tag names, x-coordindates and y co-ordinates inside the original query that was populating the original list of images. So they would execute simultaneously, then I passed the `JSONArray` values into the `model`, which then was passed to the `bind()` function in the `Adapter`.

Before, the problem was that the adapter was binding all of the tags onto every image, so when the click event happened on the image it would only add the tag to the `imageContainer` that was currently selected (in the current position), not any partiular view in any particular position.

This made it so every time the image was clicked it was always finding the first object in the database and assigning it to the selected image. [due to the click event triggering the `getTagInformation()` function). 
With the automation of the `getTagInformation` method within the `Bind` function of the `ViewHolder`, I was able to populate every image with the correct tags and further manipulate it using an `onClickListener` assigned to the image as shown below:

**RecyclerView Holder:**

```
public class RecyclerViewHolderPreviousPosts extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        // View holder for gridview recycler view as we used in listview
        public TextView createdAt;
        public ImageView uploadedImage;
        public TextView caption;
        TextView number_of_likes;
        TextView number_of_comments;
        TextView number_of_tags;
        public ImageView comments;
        public RelativeLayout imageContainer;


    RecyclerViewHolderPreviousPosts(View view) {
        super(view);
        // Find all views ids
        this.createdAt = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.created_date);
        this.uploadedImage = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.image);
        this.caption = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.caption_post);
        this.number_of_likes = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.number_of_likes);
        this.number_of_comments = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.number_of_comments);
        this.number_of_tags = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.number_of_tags);
        this.comments = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.comments_image);
        this.imageContainer = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.image_container);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void bind(PreviousPostsDataModel model1, final int position) { ....
        model = previousPostsList.get(position);
        getTagInformation();
....}

    private void getTagInformation() {
        for (int o = 0; o < model.getTagSize(); o++) {
            tag = new TextView(App.getContext());
            tag.setX(Float.parseFloat(model.getXpoints(o)));
            tag.setY(Float.parseFloat(model.getYpoints(o)));
            Log.e("x", "" + tag.getX());
            Log.e("y", "" + tag.getY());
            tag.setText(model.getTagName(o));
            tag.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tag.setMaxLines(1);
            tag.setTextSize(11);
            tag.setClickable(true);
            tag.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tag.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tags_rounded_corners);
            imageContainer.addView(tag);
            tags.add(tag);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (count == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++) {
                tags.get(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            count = 1;
        }
        else {
            for (int j = 0; j < tags.size(); j++) {
                tags.get(j).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Profile Fragment [Original Query] :**

```
private void populateSelectedUserRecyclerView(String objectid) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FashionFeed");
        query.whereEqualTo("uploader", ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", objectid));
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        Log.e("get order", "ordered");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                Log.e("gets done", "gets into done");
                if(e == null) {
                    if (objects.size() > 0) {
                        Log.e("does it get here", "it got here");

                        latestPostList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (ParseObject j : objects) {
                            JSONArray tagNamesArray = j.getJSONArray("tagName");
                            JSONArray posXArray = j.getJSONArray("tagPointX");
                            JSONArray posYArray = j.getJSONArray("tagPointY");
                            latestPostList.add(new PreviousPostsDataModel(tagNamesArray, posXArray, posYArray));
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        no_follow_display.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        no_follow_display.setText(R.string.no_posts);
                        no_follow_display.bringToFront();
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterPreviousPosts(getActivity(), latestPostList, listener);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);// set adapter on recyclerview

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("failed", "failed" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Hi @BIW please follow below link [link](https://github.com/subbuboyapati/MovieMasti/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/subbu/moviemasti/adapter/MovieAdapter.java)

In `onBindViewHolder`, you are adding listener every time, so it returns same object every time as recyclerView ViewHolder pattern uses same object to render recyclerView item in `onBindViewHolder`. So you need to add when you are creating holder object and set listener to it so that you will get a proper position.

```
package com.subbu.moviemasti.adapter;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.subbu.moviemasti.Constants;
import com.subbu.moviemasti.R;
import com.subbu.moviemasti.entities.Movie;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

/**
 * Created by subrahmanyam on 25-11-2015.
 */
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Movie> movieList;
    private onRecyclerViewItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public MovieAdapter(List<Movie> movieList) {
        this.movieList = movieList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
        String imageUrl = Constants.MOVIE_POSTER_BASE_URL + movie.getPosterPath();
        if (imageUrl != null) {
            Picasso.with(holder.posterImage.getContext()).load(imageUrl).
                    placeholder(R.drawable.img_default).
                    into(holder.posterImage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movieList.size();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(onRecyclerViewItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface onRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
        void onItemClickListener(View view, int position);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Bind(R.id.poster)
        ImageView posterImage;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

}
```

Where we are creating adaper object, from there we need to set listener
like `adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this)`

```
class MyActivity extendsActivity implements onRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    manager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), cols);
            gridView.setLayoutManager(manager); 
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
 @Override
        public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position) {
            //Do wantever you want to do
        }
}
```

From ViewHolder class we need to pass `position` of a `recyclerView` or we can write code what you need to execute when click on item.

Comment: and where would you be referring to me inside this 'link'? even if the answer is correct, the link could easily break at anytime in the future and the information will be gone. can you update your answer with the correct references to what you would like me to follow?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate more, you can't just copy and paste your own code. I need you to explain how this relates to my situation and why mine isn't working in comparison to yours, for example? I want to learn this problem so I don't run into it again, I'm not looking for a quick fix nor easy way to fix it, I'm looking to learn why mine is how it is.

Comment: Yes, it has impact with your implementation.Check latest edit.

Comment: @BIW, have you tested?

Comment: I have, it doesn't change anything except now it doesn't put the tags on all the images but only the last one in the recyclerView when i click on any image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124272/discussion-between-subrahmanyam-boyapati-and-biw).

Comment: I know this isn't the accepted answer, you'll get the auto-bounty reward of half, for your effort and guidance on the way to me discovering the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly question the problem is that ParseQuery don't return objects in the same order. So the assumptions that position of object in Your RecycleView is the same as in ParseDatabase is wrong.

If u want to get TAG from Sashido You should firstly make some relations to Images e.g additional column. Then make query white extra parameter like:

`private static final String UNIQ_TAG_ID= "tagId";
query.whereContainedIn(UNIQ_TAG_ID, id);`

or get All ParseObjects like u doing now and find that TAG that correspond to Your image, then take info.

Comment: I did this, if i manually put in the objectId from the database, the correct tags show up but still show up for all the images. So i don't believe it is the query. its getting all the information i need, but for only one set of tags. surely it must be outside the 'getTagInformation()' method.